# How to resolve "Unable to load Schema " Error in ARM template?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to create a Resource Group using the below ARM template.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2018-05-01/subscriptionDeploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.1",
    "parameters": {
        "rgName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "rgLocation": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups",
            "apiVersion": "2018-05-01",
            "location": "[parameters('rgLocation')]",
            "name": "[parameters('rgName')]",
            "properties": {}
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {}
}
```

And the Parameter file is

```
 {
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2018-05-01/subscriptionDeploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "rgName": {
      "value": "sriram"
    },
    "rgLocation": {
      "value": "southcentralus"
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any mistake in the above json files. Because am getting the following error.

```
Unable to load schema from 'https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2018-05-01/subscriptionDeploymentTemplate.json'. No schema request service available(768)
```

I ignored this error and tried running these templates in the Azure pipeline and got the following error.

```
"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/****-****-*****-****/resourcegroups/<Rsource Group Name>/providers/Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups/<new RG name>?api-version=2018-05-01'
```

Can anyone help me out? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your parameters file should use this `https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2018-05-01/subscriptionDeploymentParameters.json#` as a schema reference.

Answer (score 0):

The schema your parameter file are using does not has affect on the creation of resource groups. With the command and your original script

```
az deployment create --template-file tem.json --parameters @para.json --location southcentralus
```

I could [create the new resource group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/deploy-to-subscription#schema):

[image]

[image]

---

The error you are facing just caused by you are trying to create a new resource group [**within** a exists resource group](https://github.com/krnese/AzureDeploy/issues/23#issuecomment-511869093). This does not allowed.

Here suggest you using `Command line` task to achieve what you want, by using the command I show you above.

```
az deployment create --template-file $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/{Template}.json --parameters @$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/{parameter}.json --location southcentralus
```